# Sending Server-Sent-Events through a socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, server-sent-events

I have a C-application that produces data I want to push to a website using server-sent-events.

I implemented a basic web server in C that sends the Http-Header after receiving the Http request and then the Data in 1 sec intervals through a socket.

I registered my socket as Event-Source and I'm transmitting a correct HTTP-Header(according to Firebug), but for some reason the eventListener is not called.

```
var source = new EventSource('http://192.168.2.113:10001/'); 

source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
/* */
}, false);
```

I tried sending the events from a php application and it worked without any problems, so guess the problem is not on the javascript side.

When I just open `http://192.168.2.113:10001/` in my browser, the data strings I'm sending in 1 sec intervals are displayed.

I only found sse implementations using php or cgi, which I don't want to use.

My response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n
Date: Fri, 05 Jul 2013 15:05:15 GMT\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\n
Transfer-Encoding: chunked\n
Content-Type: text/event-stream\n
\n
```

The Event Data:

```
data: Testdata...\n\n
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the C code part of how to sending sse? I'm really curious about this and I'm looking for some example to play with. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `chunked` encoding, each chunk of data is preceded by a line describing the size of the chunk. You do not show that you are providing this size, so your event data does not follow the `chunked` encoding format.

The length is specified in hexadecimal, so in your case, the 18 bytes of data would be encoded as `12` in hexadecimal. When there are no more chunks (that is, the response is complete), then a `0` sized chunk is sent.

Many clients will accept a plain `\n` as a proper data unit terminator, but the HTTP RFC specifies that `\r\n` be used. So, each `\n` in your header should be changed to `\r\n`. and your chunks should look like:

```
12\r\ndata: Testdata...\n\r\n
```

The general rule for HTTP applications is: Be liberal about what you accept, be conservative about what you send. This rule means that you should write your application to tolerate loose interpretations of the specification, but deliver data that follows the specification strictly.

Comment: Should the header also include the size? I am using wire shark and I see it also specifies the length at the beginning. Also, there is the end chunk with size zero right?

Comment: @Timtianyang: There is no need for `Content-Length` when using `chunked` encoding. Yes, terminating chunk has size `0`, as stated in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Each line in an HTTP header needs to be terminated using `\r\n`.

See [rfc2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) section 2.2 Basic Rules

> ```
>    CR             = <US-ASCII CR, carriage return (13)>
>    LF             = <US-ASCII LF, linefeed (10)>
> ```
>
> HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker for
>   all    protocol elements except the entity-body

Your example just uses `\n` so the headers may appear to all be part of a single line to some simple http clients.  Try changing to ending each line that isn't part of the entity using `\r\n`

Comment: also after the last line of HTTP header. It should be terminated with "\r\n" 2 times

Comment: @DennyMathew It looks like that is being done correctly (see the `\n` in the line after the `Content-Type` header in the question)

Comment: ,, oh k.. just made an assertion only... tnx